# Unable to build application with Room in my test App

Tags: kotlin, android-room, kapt

When I try to build the app it gives me an error

```
Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction
   > java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)
```

In build.gradle I specified

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

and

```
implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.1"
kapt 'android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1'
```

My database class

```
@Database(entities = [WeatherOfCities::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
public abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase(){
    public abstract fun weatherOfCitiesDao(): WeatherOfCitiesDao
    companion object {
        private var INSTANCE: AppDatabase? = null
        fun getDatabase(context: Context): AppDatabase {
            if (INSTANCE == null) {
                synchronized(this) {
                    INSTANCE =
                        Room.databaseBuilder(context, AppDatabase::class.java, "database")
                            .build()
                }
            }
            return INSTANCE!!
        }
    }
}
```

My entity class

```
@Entity
data class WeatherOfCities (
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Long,
    val city: String,
    val weather: Int
)
```

My Dao interface

```
@Dao
interface WeatherOfCitiesDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM weatherOfCities")
    fun getAll(): List<WeatherOfCities>
    @Insert
    fun insert(weatherOfCities: WeatherOfCities)
    @Update
    fun update(weatherOfCities: WeatherOfCities)
}
```

And Build db in MainActivity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), MainView {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        var presenter = (application as MVPApplication).mainPresenter
        presenter?.attachView(this)
        var db = AppDatabase.getDatabase(this)
        var weatherOfCitiesDao = db.weatherOfCitiesDao()
    }
}
```

Why is the application not building and is it due to errors in the application code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the ktx dependency e.g.

```
implementation 'androidx.room:room-ktx:1.1.1'
```

I'd also suggest using 2.4.1 for all the room dependencies rather than 1.1.1

So using 2.4.1, .allowMainThreadQueries() (in the AppDatabase before .build()

And

```
    //var presenter = (application as MVPApplication).mainPresenter
    //presenter?.attachView(this)
    var db = AppDatabase.getDatabase(this)
    var weatherOfCitiesDao = db.weatherOfCitiesDao()
    weatherOfCitiesDao.insert(WeatherOfCities(0,"London",10))
    weatherOfCitiesDao.insert(WeatherOfCities(0,"Paris",20))
    weatherOfCitiesDao.update(WeatherOfCities(2,"New York", 30))
    for(woc: WeatherOfCities in weatherOfCitiesDao.getAll()) {
        Log.d("DBINFO","ID =  ${woc.id} City is ${woc.city} Weather is ${woc.weather}")
    }
```

The result written to the log is :-

```
D/DBINFO: ID =  1 City is London Weather is 10
D/DBINFO: ID =  2 City is New York Weather is 30
```

Via App Inspection :-

[image]

Comment: thx, replaced this implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.1"
kapt 'android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1' to implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.4.1"
    kapt 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.4.1' and working now

Comment: @TheDeMoN good, always better to use the latest stable versions at least as they are improving Room and adding more functionality. Have fun.